# Why is this a valid partition of a sample space?

Tags: probability

I've just viewed this page
[exercise for the Law of Total Probability](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/maths/teaching/probability/probtheory/totalprob_ex/index.html).

The problem I'm having understanding this page is that I cannot see how a sample space has been defined such that its probability is equal to 1. This is because the sum of the probabilities of the boxes does not equal 1, yet it is considered a partition of the sample space.

I am looking for clarification of how the Law of Total Probability can be applied here given that from my perspective, the sum of all boxes does not equal the sample space and thus the sum of all boxes is not actually a partition. (Most likely misunderstanding on my part).

Comment: Can you paraphrase the question? It's a little bit cumbersome.

Comment: @jay-sun updated hopefully slightly clearer.

Comment: Probably you can view the remaining probability, which is the probability of selecting neither boxes, with no green balls.

Comment: Are you calculating the probability of selecting a box or the probability of selecting a ball?